# Load map to ExtJS GMapPanel from Google Map URL

Tags: javascript, google-maps, url, extjs

I'm searching solution for loading map to GMapPanel ExtJS control from URL (e.g. https://www.google.pl/maps/@52.4796828,13.3844559,11z?hl=en). This link was created in http://maps.google.com website. Despite large research it's seems to be impossible.

Do you have any ideas how to load map in this way (from URL)? Do you know any other ways to implement this solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how Google does this with the @ sign in the URL.

But I can do it with a hashtag.

```
    <div id="map"></div>

<a target="_blank" href="index.php#48.86100157399595,2.335891842842086,7">Paris</a>
<a target="_blank" href="index.php#52.52147002033347,13.413565278053268,9">Berlin</a>
<a target="_blank" href="index.php#50.847982072140276,4.350390947438103,12">Brussels</a>

<style>
#map {
  height: 400px;
}
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
var map;

// reads the url, sets the map according to these values
function optionsFromUrl() {
  var settings = getLatLngZoom();
  if (settings) {
    map.setCenter( new google.maps.LatLng(settings[0], settings[1]) );
    map.setZoom( settings[2] );
  }
}
// reads the url, returns an array of values.  These values are separated by kommas in the url
function getLatLngZoom() {
  var vars = window.location.hash.substr(1).split(',');
  if (vars[0] && vars[1]) {
    return [
      Number(vars[0]),
      Number(vars[1]),
      Number(vars[2]) || 7  // this is a default zoom, in case it is missing in the URL.  Feel free to pick another value
    ];
  }
  return null;
}

function initialize() {
  var paris = new google.maps.LatLng(48.86100157399595,2.335891842842086);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: paris
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

  optionsFromUrl();
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```